# Searching for specific information in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have a program that acts like a local login/signup system. It asks the user if they want to signup, or login. If they signup, they shall type a username and password in a certain format and it puts it in a file.

If they choose to login, the program will assume that what they're about to type in is located in the file. The intended use is that if it is in the file, it will say that *the account is valid.* If the thing that the user typed in isn't located in the file, it should say that *it is not a valid account.*

As of now, the output always says that the account isn't valid, even though it is in the file. Here is the login portion of the code:

```
elif sol == "l":
os.system("clear")
print("You have chosen to login.")
time.sleep(2)
os.system("clear")

datasearch = input("What is your username and password?(username/password): ")

with open ("user_database.txt", "r") as searchdata:
    if datasearch in os.linesep:
        os.system("clear")
        print("This is a valid account!")
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system("clear")
        quit()
    else:
        os.system("clear")
        print("This is not a valid account!")
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system("clear")
```

Comment: By the way, you really shouldn't store plain passwords in a file like that unless you are doing this just for an experiment.

Comment: Just strengthening my knowledge! If I was using this for a true password filer, then I would use some type of security system like hashing, if that's even the right term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not searching the file. You are checking if the users input is in `os.linesep`.
You should put something like `if datasearch in searchdata.read():` inplace of `if datasearch in os.linesep:` in your code.